# How to replace Mutter with Compiz to enable Wobbly effect?

Tags: gnome, compiz, mutter

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome shell, because Unity is too slow. Is there a way I can enable extra visual effects which I had in Lucid Lynx? How can I replace my Windows managers? I prefer to use Gnome 3 or Gnome classic if Compiz works.  Thanks!

Comment: If unity is too slow, then it's probably because of the 3D effects that compiz provides.

Answer (score 7):

From [the Gnome 3 Myths page](https://live.gnome.org/GNOME3Myths):

> #### I can't use Compiz with GNOME Shell!
>
> Because the GNOME Shell project wanted "tighter integration" between the panel and window manager than cooperating with the Compiz project would allow, this could actually be true. This [mailing list post](http://www.mail-archive.com/desktop-devel-list@gnome.org/msg15602.html) has more information.

Gnome Shell relies on Mutter to do its fancy work, just as Unity (3D) relies on Compiz. You can't mix and match unfortunately.

This *might* get fixed in time but I wouldn't hold my breath.

---

Gnome Classic **does** work with Compiz though. If you're happier with a panel-based setup and want the wobblyness, you can turn compiz on by running `compiz --replace`.

To turn on wobbly windows, I suggest you install `compizconfig-settings-manager` and then run `ccsm` to change the compiz settings. A word of warning: CCSM is a powerful tool without any safety latches. It's quite easy to break Compiz with it so if you do ever get stuck, you can reset your settings by running:

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz
```

Answer (score -2):

Just install Compiz from the *Ubuntu Software Centre*, and run `compiz --replace`. That should do (it if your hardware is supported).

---

You can open a *Run* dialog by pressing *Alt+F2*.